# How to install R packages without admin right?

Tags: r

It is very common question which normally people ask. However none of the existed answers helped me so far.
I am using `Windows 7`, I have already the `R` installed on my machine however, I could not install any packages .
I have tried to do as it is said [here](http://www.magesblog.com/2012/04/installing-r-packages-without-admin.html),

however, for me it is not only programming file blocked but it is a `root` that I can only be a `user`.

For example, when I try to install a package I get the following

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
  unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80.
2: package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

if I do the following, I am not sure if I really installed the package

for example

```
> setInternet2(TRUE) 
> install.packages("devtools")
also installing the dependencies ‘mime’, ‘R6’, ‘bitops’, ‘brew’, ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’, ‘memoise’, ‘whisker’, ‘evaluate’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘roxygen2’

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/mime_0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 35053 bytes (34 KB)
downloaded 34 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/R6_2.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 123320 bytes (120 KB)
downloaded 120 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/bitops_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 36011 bytes (35 KB)
downloaded 35 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/brew_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 104709 bytes (102 KB)
downloaded 102 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/httr_0.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 388330 bytes (379 KB)
downloaded 379 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/RCurl_1.95-4.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2703282 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/memoise_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16861 bytes (16 KB)
downloaded 16 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/whisker_0.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 64626 bytes (63 KB)
downloaded 63 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/evaluate_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 36884 bytes (36 KB)
downloaded 36 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rstudioapi_0.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 27315 bytes (26 KB)
downloaded 26 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/jsonlite_0.9.16.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1009930 bytes (986 KB)
downloaded 986 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/roxygen2_4.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 598652 bytes (584 KB)
downloaded 584 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.7.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 309378 bytes (302 KB)
downloaded 302 KB

package ‘mime’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘R6’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘bitops’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘brew’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘httr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘memoise’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘whisker’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘evaluate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rstudioapi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘roxygen2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\ex3446\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOYDKSd\downloaded_packages
```

Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm not admin on my work computer and whenever I use `install.packages()` it defaults to installing to my user AppData folder. It's probably somewhere in your R settings.

Comment: @Alex A. I posted an example of error I get, do you know how to solve it? how then do you install your packages ?

Comment: Select your default CRAN mirror and install directory in your R settings. For the CRAN mirror, select whichever available mirror is closest to your geographic location.

Comment: @Alex A. for sure, I did it but it did not really work. I posted all what I get as an error

Comment: seems to be a network access problem (*possibly* related to admin privileges, but seems unlikely ...) rather than a write-permission problem?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/swlazlowski/Home/hardware/using-r-behind-a-firewall

might have to fiddle with some proxy settings.

Comment: @Ben Bolker thanks for your comment, Yes it is

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a write-permission problem, as other have commented. I'd made sure your R environment is correctly set (etc it's not corrupted) by a mistake or so.

Also by reading [this](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e), you might want to set the flag `--internet2` in your R executable link and try again.

> (a) Use the Windows internet functions by starting R with the flag --internet2 or calling setInternet2(TRUE) or setting the environment variable R_WIN_INTERNET2 to a non-empty value when starting R.

Also, you might specify `install.packages` as follows to select a repository specifically:

```
install.packages("gains", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com", type = "source")
```

Comment: The edited post shows a package being installed, though. Are you still getting the previous message with `ggplot2`?

Comment: Yes, it shoys but then when i close and again run the R, it says there is not package. because it removes all installed packages

Comment: I guess it removes installed packages because you are installing them in `temp` files. Maybe change your installation directory like it's done in the link you've provided and try again?

Comment: can you please tell me how to change that ? I tried to right click on R and change it based on properties/target but it did not work

Comment: I mean your package installation directory, which is shown how to be done in the link you've provided, using `.libPaths`

Comment: I tried to set it somewhere else but i got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem with R-Studio? As I was facing same issue while installing packages using R-Studio. After trying all solutions which didn't work for me. I switched to R and I could install packages.